# recovering deleted script running in background

Tags: unix, process, nohup

I have script which is running in bg(nohup) but it was accidently deleted,but that is continue running now I need to edit the code which is already deleted.

How can I now get that code.I assume somewhere it should be as it is running.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! $1 || $1 == -h || $1 == --help ]]; then
    echo -e "Usage:\n\n\t$0 '[path/]<file name>'"
    exit 1
fi

files=(
    $(file 2>/dev/null /proc/*/fd/* |
        grep "(deleted)'$" | 
        sed -r 's@(:.*broken\s+symbolic\s+link\s+to\s+.|\(deleted\).$)@ @g' |
        grep "$1" |
        cut -d' ' -f1
    )
)

if [[ ${files[@]} ]]; then
    for f in ${files[@]}; do
        echo "fd $f match... Try to copy this fd to another place quickly!"
    done
else
    echo >&2 "No matching fd found..."
    exit 2
fi
```

Not tested on non GNU-Linux

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/accept if the answer fit your needs. Check http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote and http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: The file is a character Spl file with,no permission how to resolve this

Comment: You should have read permission, try to copy : `cp /dev/fd42 /tmp/backup`. It's not a file intented to be opened by an editor. It's a special file

Comment: There are no permission on that but owning it.The type permission field are like below : c--------- user grp......